# link_to doesnt replace div's content

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

the relevant controller code:

```
def show_host
  queue = TestQueue.find(params[:id])
  @test_queues = TestQueue.where(:host => queue.host)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render action: "show_host", :layout => nil}
    format.json { render json: @test_queue }
  end
end
```

view:

```
<iframe name="host_queues", scrolling="yes" width="82%" height="700px", align="right", frameborder="0", rel="stylesheet"></iframe>
<%= link_to host, { :controller => "test_queues", :action => "show_host", :id => id}, {:target => "host_queues"} %>
```

now the thing is, it works with replace the content of the iframe, but when i try to replace content in a div with class="host_queues", it doesnt work... works only with iframe ..

can any1 out a finger on the reason ? 10x ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target` only applies to frames and windows. You have to use Javascript to replace the contents of a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

use remote: true option in link_to  and than write javascript
OR 
use form_tag with remote: true, in update option, give div id which you want to replace

you can chek below link

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html